# Is there a way to delay a QueueMessage in Azure Functions?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-storage-queues

I need to submit a message to Queue Storage, but not have it immediately trigger a function that is bound to that queue. In this basic example, I want to submit a message to a queue so that it triggers a function 1 minute later:

```
def main(msg: func.QueueMessage, outputQueueItem: func.Out[func.QueueMessage]) -> None:
    data = msg.get_json()

    # Do some fancy stuff

    message = func.QueueMessage(body=json.dumps({"spam": 1, "eggs": "ham"}))

    # This causes an AttributeError since you cant set time_next_visible
    message.time_next_visible = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(minutes=1)

    outputQueueItem.set(message)

    # More fancy stuff down here
```

I could throw in a `time.sleep(60)` before submitting the message, but that seems like bad practice, plus it would delay any other code below the line submitting the message and increase the billing cost of running the function. This is especially bad if there is a large delay necessary (e.g. an hour).

Is there any good way to delay the message from triggering the next function immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python can not use durable functions, so you have two ways to realize your ideas.

First is as you says, use sleep to make it wait.

Second is from the **`Python Azure SDK`**, use the `put_message` method to make the message stay in the queue(set the `Visibility`), take a look of how to use [put_message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-queue/azure.storage.queue.queueservice.queueservice?view=azure-python#put-message-queue-name--content--visibility-timeout-none--time-to-live-none--timeout-none-).

Comment: Thanks... I think I'll go with this. I was really hoping there was a way to do it with a queue binding, something like `outputQueueItem.set(message, time_next_visible=60)` or something similar.